# print div content using print media css

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print the HTML page which contains a `div` with lots of content inside it. The HTML of the page is as follows:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <ol>
          <li>Content goes here</li>
          <li>Content goes here</li>
          .....
          .....
       </ol>
       <ol>
          <li>Content goes here</li>
          <li>Content goes here</li>
          .....
          .....
       </ol>
       ...............
       ...............
   </div>
</div>
```

The print media css is as follows:

```
@media print{
     .outer{
             display:inline;
             overflow:visible;
      }
}
```

But when I open the print preview of this page, the div content is missing. Print preview displays some content from start of `div`, then blank (about two pages) and some end content of `div`.

Comment: what are the original styles for this content?

Answer (score 0):

It should be work if you go with following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen {
    p {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}

@media print {
    .inner {
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The @media Rule</h2>

<div class="inner"><b>Test it!</b> Print this page (or open Print Preview), and you will see that the text will be displayed in blue, and in another smaller font.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I take w3school.com @media-print example and change according to your requirement it showing font changes and apply css while try to print.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, it works fine to me.

- I want to print with css @media the "Invoice" class.
- "No-print" class will be disabled.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pad margin no-print" style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:20px">
   <div id="divControl" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="margin-top:10px"></div>
</div> 
<div class="content invoice">
    <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
           <address>Dirección:</address>
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

AT THE TOP OF CSS:

```
/* Don't display when printing */    
@media print {
.no-print {
    display: none;
}
.left-side,
.header,
.content-header {
    display: none;
}
.right-side {
    margin: 0;
}
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
@page { /* with this margin, no extra blank page to me */
    margin: 0mm auto;    /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
}
```

AT THE BOTTOM OF CSS:

```
/* Enhancement for printing */
@media print {
.invoice {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.invoice-col {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333333%;
}
.table-responsive {
    overflow: auto;
}
.table-responsive > .table tr th,
.table-responsive > .table tr td {
    white-space: normal!important;
}
}
```